# The controller does not get bind to the view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just started learning AngularJS and facing a problem. When I run the follwing code `{{ cust.name }}` - `{{ cust.city }}` gets printed instead of the actual data that I pass.

#### My code:

```
<html data-ng-app="">
  <head>
    <title>Using angularJS directive and data binding </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
      Name:
      <br/>
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
      <br/>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust  in customers | filter:name"> {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [{
          name: 'Abhijeet Singh',
          city: 'New Delhi'
        }, {
          name: 'Dhiraj Mehta , city: New Delhi '
        }];
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Currently your javascript code contains just a function. So there is no work for angular to do. You need to bind your view, as well as js to an module.

Comment: you appear to be trying to follow an *ancient* tutorial;  a blank `ng-app` hasn't been allowed in angular since angular 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are missing from your code.

First it is good practice to name your app and a controller:

```
<body data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myCtrl'>
```

Second whenever you refer to anything in Angular is has to be in scope of the controller. Currently your $scope is in scope of the "SimpleController" function and not of Angular's controller (you need an angular controller to have $scope available both within the controller and within your html e.g. the double curly brackets):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
//$scope is available anywhere within this scope
}
```

Here is an example of your code working: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/03hshn5m/

Comment: <body data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myController'>

<div>
    Name:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model = "name" />
    <br/>
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat = "cust  in customers | filter:name"> {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
<script src = /home/abhijeet/Desktop/javascript.js></script>
<scrpit src = /home/abhijeet/Desktop/angular.min.js></script>   (this is the html code)

Comment: var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.customers  = [
        { name: 'Abhijeet Singh',city: 'New Delhi'  },
        { name: 'Dhiraj Mehta' , city: 'New Delhi'}
      ];

});    (this is the javascript code)

Comment: the issue still remains

Comment: The code you posted works: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/03hshn5m/2/     Make sure you are using at least angular 1.4.8 preferably 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare the app name and see the other settings.

Rest of the things are same.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
var simpleController = angular.module("SimpleController", SimpleController);

simpleController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function SimpleController($scope){
   $scope.customers = [{
          name: 'Abhijeet Singh',
          city: 'New Delhi'
        }, {
          name: 'Dhiraj Mehta , city: New Delhi '
        }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html data-ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <title>Using angularJS directive and data binding </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
      Name:
      <br/>
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
      <br/>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust  in customers | filter:name"> {{cust.name }}-{{cust.city}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I have started learning Angular today. Can you please suggest me the tuts / book I should  start with. :)